# Using jQuery show() / hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `show()` and `hide()` in my jsp page, and it is working fine, but I am having trouble figuring out a way to hide my table once it is shown. HTML EX:

```
<button id="b1">show 1</button>
<button id="b2">show 2</button>
<div class="hidden" id="d1">
<div class="hidden" id="d2">
```

So basically I want to show `div1` when `button1` is clicked, and show `div2` when `button2` is clicked.  I am using `hide()`/`show()` because I never want both to show at the same time.  So here is my script:

```
  $('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#d1').show();
    $('#d2').hide();
  });

  $('#b2').click(function(){
    $('#d2').show();
    $('#d1').hide();
  });
```

So this works fine, as far as showing only one at a time, but I want to add some script to this to make it where if `div2` is showing, I can click on `button2` and make `div2` hide, and the same thing for `div1`.  I know this is confusing so if you have any questions please ask. thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. It sounds like the script you posted does what you want. If you could clarify exactly what the issue is you're running into?

Comment: if you want to show one and hide another.  then you should look into using toggle.

Comment: Are you looking for a toggle? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: If i use toggle, it would show both, and I was trying to avoid that, I think I have it worked out now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#d2').hide();
     $('#d1').toggle();
});

$('#b2').click(function(){
     $('#d1').hide();
     $('#d2').toggle();

});
```

Comment: ah, so simple.  Works perfectly, thank you.  Will mark as answer when allowed

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#d1').toggle();
});

$('#b2').click(function(){
    $('#d2').toggle();
});
```

If you need to still make it so that only one can be shown then probably something like this:

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
    if($('#d1').toggle().is(":visible")){
       $('#d2').hide();
    }
});

$('#b2').click(function(){
    if($('#d2').toggle().is(":visible")){
       $('#d1').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check anything, just toggle the first one and always hide the other one

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#d1').toggle();
    $('#d2').hide();
});

$('#b2').click(function(){
    $('#d2').toggle();
    $('#d1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `toggle()` method that you can use instead of show/hide that will do this for you.

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility
>   of elements:

Source: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#b1').click(function(){
    $('#d1').toggle();
  });

  $('#b2').click(function(){
    $('#d2').toggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use any animation, it is probably more useful to define a class in css, say, .hidden {display:"none"} and toggle it.

Thus, you code can be something like this:

```
$("#b1, #b2").click(function() { $("#d1, d2").toggleClass("hidden") })
```

Try this one, if you want, and tell us, whether it works )

Answer (score -1):

You can check if something is visible by this `$('#someDiv:visible')` and then do appropriate handling.